# rich:calendar update backing bean after component edit

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

I have a rich:calendar component in a datatable:

```
 <rich:column id="last_#{row.index}" >
   <rich:calendar id="lcal_#{row.index}"
     value="#{_obj.list[row.index].lastTaught}">
     <a4j:support event="onchanged"
       action="#{_obj.list[row.index].setBooleanDateHasBeenChanged}"
       ajaxSingle="true" reRender="last_#{row.index}" /> 
   </rich:calendar>
 </rich:column>
```

When a user changes the date I need to set a field to true (I need to know what row was changed for db update later, I want to update a bunch of rows at once):

```
 /**
 * when someone changes the last taught field, set has been edited to true
 */
public void resetHasBeenEdited(){
    this.hasBeenEdited = true;
}
```

When I change the date the setBooleanDateHasBeenChanged method is called and the _obj.list is updated in the backing bean, but when I examine _obj after the rerender, the hasBeenEdited field does not reflect the change.

I tried using a valueChangeListener (changed method signature to match):

```
 <rich:column id="last_#{row.index}" >
   <rich:calendar id="lcal_#{row.index}"
     value="#{_obj.list[row.index].lastTaught}"
         valueChangeListener="#{_obj.list[row.index].setBooleanDateHasBeenChanged}">
     <a4j:support event="onchanged"
       ajaxSingle="true" reRender="last_#{row.index}" /> 
   </rich:calendar>
 </rich:column>
```

But then setBooleanDateHasBeenChanged doesn't even run.
How do I get an action to update the backing bean AND reflect that change in the rerendered JSF model?
I'm using JSF1.2, RF3.3 and Seam2.2.

Comment: The `valueChangeListener` method must follow a different signature than the simple `setXXX` method, something like `public void valueChangeMethod(ValueChangeEvent e){ ... }`. Not sure if this change would satisfy your requirement. By the way, **do not edit the `setXXX` method**, use another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a bunch of different configurations, but what finally worked was getting rid of ajaxSingle and reRender:

```
 <rich:column id="last_#{status.index}"     
      <rich:calendar value="#{_obj.list[row.index].lastTaught}" >
      <a4j:support event="onchange"
         actionListener="#{_obj.list[row.index].resetTaughtHasBeenEdited()}"/>
    </rich:calendar>
 </rich:column>
```

The reRender action would just reset the displayed value to its previous setting and ajaxSingle wouldn't update the model.